# How to join table from one database with view from another database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `TableA` in database `A` and view `ViewB` in database `B`

I am trying to simply join the table with the view to write a query. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEA a, B.VIEWB b 
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

However, it is not working.

What is the way to join a table and a view from different databases? Should I be creating a synonym?....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use three part naming or create a Synonym.

3-part naming would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseA.Schema.TABLEA a
join DatabaseB.Schema.VIEWB b ON a.id = b.id
```

Creating a synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM DatabaseB_ViewB
FOR DatabaseB.Schema.VIEWB;
GO

USE DatabaseA
GO

SELECT * 
FROM TABLEA a
join DatabaseB_ViewB b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I think I would prefer the synonym approach. Should I be creating the synonym in DatabaseB?

Comment: Create the synonym in the database where its going to be used.